# Edit link for Favorite Tags is not accessible

Tags: bug, tags, accessibility

The Favorite Tags widget which appears on the right sidebar of every Stack Exchange community's homepage is not keyboard accessible because the "Edit" link does not contain a `href` attribute.  The HTML appears as:

```
<h4 id="h-interesting-tags">Favorite Tags</h4>
<a id="edit-interesting">edit</a>
```

In terms of WCAG, this is a level A failure of [2.1.1 Keyboard](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation-keyboard-operable.html).  The obvious fix is to add the required `href`, but given its purpose as a UI control, it probably makes more semantic sense as a button.